# Is there anything stopping me from making my own NFT of an existing NFT?

Tags: cryptocurrency

I feel like I some understanding of cryptocurrencies, but what never made sense to me are NFTs. This is my current understanding of NFT's

- NFT's are a type of smart contract
- Smart contracts aren't necessarily open source, but you do have access to the bytecode
- The actual NFT isn't stored on the blockchain, but rather on a file hosting server

So if I have access to the smart contract's bytecode and the NFT's image, whats stopping me (if anything) from just minting my own copy of somebody else's NFT? And lets say if I were to do this, what is separating mine from the original NFT?

Not entirely sure this is the best place to ask but I couldn't really think of a better place.

Comment: Err, how do you intent to issue an NFT without something like Ethereum blockchain?

Comment: You mean the actual digital asset is stored on the file server(?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mint an NFT referring to an identical image or other digital asset someone else created.
This may or may not be a copyright infringement.

It will be clear you minted the new one and not the original creator, and it would be clear your NFT was created later and first arrived on the ledger after the original.

They may have the same image but one came first. If owning the first is considered more valueable than it is more valueable. If.you think none of these have any value, than they don't.